# WPF Set the Corner Radius of a Border through a Converter

Tags: xaml, listview, border, converters

I would like to set the bottom Corner Radius of a ListView Item for just the "last" item in the list. I've attempted to do so with a Converter (which in fact finds the last row), but to no avail.

The desirable effect is when the Converter returns true after finding the last item in the ListView, the border CornerRadius on the last ListViewItem is set to CornerRadius="0,0,10,10". For all other items in the ListView, CornerRadius="0,0,0,0"

What I've done so far.

The Converter...

```
public class IsLastItemConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       #region IValueConverter Members
       public object TrueValue { get; set; }
       public object FalseValue { get; set; }

       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
        ListViewItem item = value as ListViewItem;
        ListView listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
        if (listView != null)
        {

            int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
            if (index == listView.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                TrueValue = true;
                return (bool)TrueValue;
            }
            else
            {
                FalseValue = false;
                return (bool)FalseValue;
            }

        }
            FalseValue = false;
            return (bool)FalseValue;
       }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
        // Just Convert Back
        return true;
       }
       #endregion
   }
```

The XAML...

```
<local:IsLastItemConverter x:Key="lastItemConverter" 
                                   TrueValue="0,0,10,10" FalseValue="0,0,0,0"/>


<DataTemplate x:Key="CellContentTemplate">
                        <Border 
                            x:Name="CellContentBorder"
                            Background="{StaticResource GrayCharcoal}"                          
                            BorderThickness="4,4,4,4"                           
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource Gray}"
                            CornerRadius="{Binding Converter={StaticResource lastItemConverter}, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Width="210" 
                            Height="50"                         
                            ContextMenu="{StaticResource MarginalUnitsContextMenu}" 
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">...
```

Thoughts and ideas much appreciated - Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try returning a real CornerRadius instead of a string (which, you are essentially returning).

My assumption is following:
<strike>When passing as string "0,0,0,0" in xaml as CornerRadius, the appropriate Converter is used to convert this string in to a CornerRadius struct.</strike>

As you are now using a custom converter, possibly the string to CornerRadius Converter is not anymore used...

EDIT (in light of Clemens answer): The Converter for the property does seem to kick in when a string was returned from the custom converter associated with the binding!
This is because CornerRadius has an associated TypeConverter:

```
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(CornerRadiusConverter))]
public struct CornerRadius : IEquatable<CornerRadius>
```

which handles this conversion. This converter handles the Conversion from string to CornerRadius.
(Taken from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx )

Comment: Daniel - thanks very much for the suggestion. Returning the string in the desired format really did the trick. I'm a bit new to submissions on this forum, so let me know if/how I can give you credit. Glenn

Comment: For everyone's benefit, the end result was accomplished by modifying the return inside the Converter. if true, return "0,0,10,10"; - Glenn

Comment: Hi Glenn, nice that it worked out. If the answer is the right answer then you can accept it, if you like it you can upvote it.

Comment: @Daniel Just for your information, the problem was that OP returned a `bool` from its converter, not a string.

Comment: Daniel - I set as accepted. Unfortunately I'm too new to vote up. Thanks - Glenn

Comment: @user2284452 Even better than returning a string would be to return a [CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius.aspx), as Daniel has suggested.

Comment: Clemens: yep, from Glenns answer I assumed this. So, Converters are "chainable" I guess, or at least the default converter for the CornerRadius does kick in after the converter associated with the binding has done its work, this is actually really nice to know.

Comment: @Daniel Converters aren't "chainable". Actually there are two kinds of converters. The default conversion from string to CornerRadius is done by a `TypeConverter`, whereas bindings use `IValueConverter`.

Comment: Thanks Clements, I checked this, Type converters are added to a class with a TypeConverterAttribute... will update my answer. Big thanks for expanding my knowledge on this topic.